# Vim regex matching with lookahead and suffix without destroy the lookahead behavior

Tags: regex, vim

*Think about two different highlight match in vim
Pattern 1.
    syn match match1 /\$[^$ ]+\$/
Match `$foo$`, `$bar$`, `$123$`
Pattern 2.
    syn match match2 /(\w+\|(\$[^\$]+\$)\@=)+__/
I want it match `foo$bar$__` but not `$bar$`
The problem is Pattern1 will conflict with Pattern2.
I'm trying to use Positive Lookahead to bypass Pattern1 in Pattern2,
but the prefix `__` (Double underscores) destroy the behavior of Positive lookahead.
How do I solve this issue? or i'm doing something wrong !?*

---

**Update:**

Sorry for bad explanation.

Pattern 1 match any string surrounded by two dollar signs

```
syn match match1 /\$[^$ ]\+\$/
-> $foo$, $bar$
```

Pattern 2 match any string end with double underscores BUT match still but exclude any string that match as Pattern1.

```
syn match match2 /\(\w\+\|\(\$[^\$]\+\$\)\@=\)\+__/
-> hello__, world__
```

so the problem is when I add any string related to pattern 1

```
hello$foo$__
```

in this case. I want hello AND __ match with pattern 1(Continuous)

but also let $foo$ match with pattern 2.

Comment: If I give you a PCRE regex, can you convert it to _vim_ ?

Comment: Well, in PCRE, and without any _boundary_ added info, it is this `(?:\w+\$[^$ ]+\$__|\$[^$ ]+\$)`. Don't need a lookahead really. Convert to _vim_ syntax as needed.

Comment: And if you want to totally disallow `__` after a `$aa$` (unless matched with a `foo` before it), add the assertion after the `\$[^$ ]+\$` clause, like this `(?:\w+\$[^$ ]+\$__|\$[^$ ]+\$(?!__))`

Comment: I don't understand your pattern 2. Can you describe in English what it is supposed to match?

Comment: For the first syntax pattern you could use: `/\v\$[^$ ]+\$(_)@!/`. This will match words between dollar signs when not followed by underscore (example: `$foo$`). For the second pattern: `/\v\w+\$[^$]+\$__/`. This will match a word, followed by a word between dollar signs, followed by double underscore (example: `foo$bar$__`)

Comment: @sln Deepy sorry for bad description. I'm not trying to lookahead those two underscores.
I've updated my question for better explanation.

Comment: @melpomene Second pattern is match any string as follow (Single quote mean exclude)
foo_ |
foobar__ | 
foo'$bar$'__ |
foo'$bar$'baz__ | 
$foo$'bar__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you understand what lookahead does. It looks like what you're trying to do is to match a string, but skip over parts of it:

```
foo$bar$___
^^^~~~~~^^^
```

... where the parts marked `^` form the match proper (discontinous) and the parts marked `~` are skipped over.

This is not possible with a regex. A regex always matches a continuous piece of string.

What lookahead does is it lets you "peek ahead": It matches a sub-regex as usual, but does not move the current position within the string. Depending on where you put the lookahead, this lets you either check text beyond the end of the match or make sure the same string is matched by two regexes simultaneously (although the latter can also be done with `\&` in vim).

Example:

```
\%(foo\)\@=bar
```

This can never match. It requires the next three characters to be both `foo` and `bar` at the same time, which is impossible.

---

I think what you're looking for is overlapping matches. Vim supports this directly:

```
syn match match1 /\$[^$ ]\+\$/
syn match match2 /\%(\w\|\$[^$ ]\+\$\)\+__/ contains=match1
```

Here we're saying matches of `match2` can contain matches of `match1`. This gives you the highlighting you want.